# program not leaving while loop

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

[Hey guys, i have this while loop for variable 'i' and i have created a board[][] which is 2x2 (so sizeX for the board is 2 in this example). The problem is i can't work out why it isn't leaving the while loop if it goes through one of the 'if' statements starting with 'i=1' and then it then sets 'i=i+1' (=2) but doesn't leave the while statement and tries to see what board[2][x] is equal to when obviously that is out of the bounds of the board. Sorry for confusing explanation i hope you understand...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvjBP.png)

Comment: there are cases in which you don't change the value of x.

Comment: so does it have to leave while loop for x before it can leave the one for i?

Comment: First: you should not post the whole message of your post as a link and second: you can put source code directly into your post (without using an external image). That would make it even easier to read your question and your code simultaneously. ;-)

Comment: Please format question better.

Comment: You should check your outer `else` statement. Either this would cause your inner loop to run forever (it does not change the value of `x`) or crash your application (negative index).

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you are new to programming because you are using BlueJ.
When your second loop is running, I'm guessing that your line x=x is keeping x within range and hence the loop never exits.

One good thing to help is to use a debugger or print statements to show what the values of x and i are at each stage. That will quickly let you know what is going wrong.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: User asked why program was not leaving the loop. My answer was stating because x was staying within range.